# Random Forest Call Error

Tags: random-forest

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q69bz.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN0bH.jpg)

library(randomForest)
rfModel2 = randomForest(formula = Purchased~., data = Network, ntree = 50, importance = TRUE, replace=TRUE)

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'User ID' not found

The User ID is unique and not needed, how can I get the function to ignore this and work on the 1/0 Purchased column?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Is purchased a value or a factor?

Assuming it is a factor (0: Not Purchased, 1: Purchased for Instance) you will do classification using the following code:

```
df$Purchased<-as.factor(as.character(df$Purchased))
df$Gender<-as.factor(as.character(df$Gender))
rfModel2<-randomForest(Purchased~.,data=df[,-1])
```

UserID not included in the calculation

Now if Purchased is a number, meaning the number of items purchased, you should go with regression:

```
df$Gender<-as.factor(df$Gender)
rfModel2<-randomForest(Purchased~.,data=df[,-1])
```

and you will get a warning due to the fact that your response variable seems to be a factor

```
> df$Gender<-as.factor(df$Gender)
> rfModel2<-randomForest(Purchased~.,data=df[,-1])
Warning message:
In randomForest.default(m, y, ...) :
  The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?
>
```

hope this helps